# Does reinterpreting the base of a number leave transcendence unchanged?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, transcendental-numbers

Define the 'reinterpret $x$ from base $a$ to base $b$' function $R_{a,b}(x)$ as
$$
R_{a,b}(x)=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}b^iD_{a,i}(x)
$$
where $D_{m,i}(x)$ is the $i$-th term in the $m$-ary expansion of $x$,
$$
D_{m,i}(x) = \left\lfloor m(m^{i-1}x - \lfloor m^{i-1}x\rfloor) \right\rfloor.
$$

For integers $a,b>1$, is it true that $x$ is transcendental iff $R_{a,b}(x)$ is transcendental?

For example, is 3.050330051415124105234414053125321..., $\pi$ reinterpreted from base 6 to base 10, transcendental?

Jyrki Lahtonen suggests a useful reformulation: write the base-$a$ digits of a number $x$ as a Laurent polynomial $f$ such that $f(1/a)=x$. Then the question is whether $f(1/a)$ is transcendental if and only if $f(1/b)$ is transcendental, for integers $a,b>1.$

This is probably asking too much; my hope was to prove that, say, $R_{a,b}(\pi)$ is transcendental for all integers $a,b>1$ (or substitute your favorite transcendental number). Any movement in this direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Or, if you prefer. Imagine the series
$$f(x)=3+ x+ 4x^2+x^3+5x^4+\cdots\in\Bbb{Z}[[x]]$$ such that $f(1/10)=\pi$, when the question could be whether $f(1/11)$ is also transcendental. Ok, he first converts $\pi$ to base $6$ to get another series in $g(x)=\Bbb{Z}[[x]]$, such that $g(1/6)=\pi$, and then asks about $g(1/10)$, but the idea is the same.

Comment: I guess questions like this are very difficult, but I know very little about transcendental numbers. I think the original tag [tag:number-theory] is better.

Comment: As long as we keep in "normal" number systems like a base $b$-system with integer base $b\ge 2$ , whether a number is transcendental does of course not depend on the chosen number system.

Comment: I agree that the OP is asking a highly nontrivial question.

Comment: @Peter The asker does something else. The process is a bit unnatural, and therefore it is easy to trip here. Charles is changing the number but keeping the string of digits. Not unlike whether the hexadecimal number
$$3.1415926535\ldots$$ is transcendental?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for this crucial clarification.

Comment: I would think almost certainly no, but it's surely hard to prove.  If $x$ is irrational but algebraic then there's no obvious reason not to expect $R_{a,b}(x)$ to be transcendental if $a\neq b$.

Comment: I would be very surprised if, say, $1.040104020103\ldots$ (which is $\sqrt2$ reinterpreted from base 10 to base 100) were algebraic, and if I'm right about that, then that's a counterexample. But I don't have any proof, and this may be very difficult to prove.